# Making the discrete AMD GPU the default GPU in a Mux-less setup with an integrated Intel GPU in Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, amd-radeon, xorg.conf

How do I making the discrete AMD GPU the default GPU in a Mux-less setup with an integrated Intel GPU in Mint 18?

What I've gleaned / attempted so far:

```
Information from lspci: 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) 
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X] (rev ff)
```

PRIME offloading works, but rather than append "DRI_PRIME=1" before every program to get it to run on the AMD GPU, I'd rather switch it over permanently in one place. The "Discrete Card as Primary GPU" section looks like it may be a good start, as I believe that all the outputs are actually owned by the Intel GPU (the AMD GPU just handles rendering and tosses it back to the Intel GPU...I think), but I can't get it to work (plus I need to have the outputs already functioning before I get to the Login screen, as I won't have a chance to run "xrandr --setprovideroutputsource Intel amdgpu" from a discrete output to activate the non-discrete ones).

Here is the Xorg.log from a normal bootup: http://pastebin.com/pVJriD64

And here is the gpu-manager.log from a normal bootup: http://pastebin.com/y9aE7ALN

```
Output from xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x6d cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 4 associated providers: 2 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x45 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:VERDE @ pci:0000:01:00.0
Provider 2: id: 0x45 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:VERDE @ pci:0000:01:00.0

My attempt to modify the PRIME example to get me somewhere near where I need to be:

# Discrete Card as Primary GPU

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "amdgpu"
    Inactive "Intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdgpu"
    Driver      "amdgpu"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0" # Sample: "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdgpu"
    Device "amdgpu"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel"
    Driver      "Intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"  # Sample: "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Intel"
    Device "Intel"
EndSection
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Oh, how to accomplish this: "How do I making the discrete AMD GPU the default GPU in a Mux-less setup with an integrated Intel GPU in Mint 18?"

Comment: You should edit your question, so what you are asking, is crystal clear.

Comment: You probably can't do that anyway since Optimus/PowerXpress wiring is usually fixed. You can try to check your BIOS/UEFI settings to see if there's a relevant option though.

Comment: Judging by [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME) *PRIME GPU offloading and Reverse PRIME is an attempt to support muxless hybrid graphics in the Linux kernel.* I think Reverse PRIME is what you're stating in your question. Your attempt to modify the config looks exactly like the example so I assume you got that from there. Under the installation step, did you remove the closed-source drivers and replace them with the open-source drivers?

Comment: @TomYan Using only the discrete GPU with the integrated GPU's outputs is an option in Windows, so it is doable. Clarification: the Intel GPU 'owns' the eDP1 and HDMI1 ports; the AMD GPU owns no ports; hence, when the AMD GPU renders, it either talks to the Intel GPU, or it takes over its ports (something like that, imagine). And rather than have an Intel GPU-driven desktop, with an AMD GPU-accelerated Firefox or Steam application, I want to just make everything run on the AMD GPU, possibly disabling the Intel GPU in the process.

Comment: @DrZoo New account, won't let me post more than two links on the question summary until my score increases some more...;-)

Comment: Did you successfully uninstall the closed-source drivers and install the open-source drivers? I can't view your links because pastbin is blocked on the current network. I'll have to check those out later on.

Comment: @DrZoo Yeah, that's an interesting question. I've removed the 'radeon' and 'ati' driver packages for Xorg ('amdgpu' was already installed), and yet, according to HardInfo and lspci -v, it's still loading the 'radeon' driver. Module Information: Path: /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko.

Comment: Ok, so, two things I've learned: I am already using the open-source driver (radeon), and having removed 'radeon' and various other drivers while keeping 'amdgpu' installed made things stop working, so I've reinstalled them. I've also tried subbing 'radeon' for 'amdgpu' in that file, which seems to work, right up to the point where X screams about not having any outputs.

Comment: I still got no success to do this.
In /var/log/Xorg.0.log I can see the following errors:
(EE) AMDGPU(0): No modes.
...
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration
Fatal server error
(EE) no screens found(EE)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell a login manager to execute a command as soon as it starts up, so you could have your login manager and desktop environment both execute `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource Intel amdgpu` at startup.

From [Gentoo's Nvidia Optimus wiki article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVIDIA/Optimus#Display_manager_configuration):

1. KDM: Add commands to `/usr/share/config/kdm/Xsetup`
2. SDDM: Add commands to `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup`
3. Mint DM: Add commands to `/etc/X11/mdm/Init/Default`
4. XDM: Add commands to `/usr/lib/X11/xdm/Xsetup_0` or `/usr/lib64/X11/xdm/Xsetup_0`
5. LXDM: Add commands to `/etc/lxdm/LoginReady`
   6: GDM: Create a desktop entry under `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and `/usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/`, and a line reading `X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=DisplayServer` to it.

Hope this helps!